# How to always display model data in Django template after reloading a page?

Tags: python, django

Scenario:

Currently, **my Template has a text which says "Last seen" and a timer that mentions the time generated after clicking a button**. If a new user visits the site, there will be no time displayed. If a user clicks on the button, the time will be generated and created in the model. And every time a user refreshes the page, the old/current time should be displayed near the text. Right now, every time I reload the page, there is no time displayed despite being saved in my model. How can I show the current time in my Template after reloading each time?

This is what I have tried out so far:

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Path(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    current_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)  #can be Null or blank if users enters the site for the first time.
```

views.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone 
import pytz
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse

def Func():
    '''
    If the current_time does not exist, then we create it in the Path model.
    #If time already exists, then we grab the id and replace current time with a new one using the update() method. 
    '''
    time = timezone.now()  #Format: 2019-11-16 14:53:35.774824+00:00
    user_id = request.user.id      #User id = 1
    if (Path.objects.filter(current_time = time) in (None, '')): 
        time = Path.objects.create(current_time = time)
    else:
        time = Path.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).update(current_time = time) 
    obj = Path.objects.values_list('current_time', flat=True)
    return HttpResponse(obj)
```

home.html:

```
... HTML stuff here
#If time exists in model, then display it in Template (even after refreshing/reloading)
{% if obj.current_time %}
    <div class="placeRight">
        <p> Last indexed:
            <b> {{obj.current_time}}</b> 
        </p> 
    </div>
#If time doesn't exist, then display None (this will only occur if a user enters the site for the first time). 
{% else %}
    <div class="placeRight">
        <p> Last indexed:
            <b> None </b> 
        </p> 
    </div> -->
{% endif %}
```

As stated, after each page reload, the time is displayed as 'None' and I have to keep clicking the button for the time to show up. Is there a way to view the time (if existing) after each reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You need to send a context back to the template

Here is how your view should change

```
from django.template import loader # I added this line

    def Func():
    '''
    If the current_time does not exist, then we create it in the Path model.
    #If time already exists, then we grab the id and replace current time with a new one using the update() method. 
    '''
    time = timezone.now()  #Format: 2019-11-16 14:53:35.774824+00:00
    template = loader.get_template('home.html')   # I added this line
    user_id = request.user.id      #User id = 1
    if (Path.objects.filter(current_time = time) in (None, '')): 
        time = Path.objects.create(current_time = time)
    else:
        time = Path.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).update(current_time = time) 
    obj = Path.objects.values_list('current_time', flat=True)

    context = {

            'obj':obj
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain what you did?

Comment: There are a few lines of code i have added to your original code. There is an import of the loader, the loading of a template, creating a context dictionary applying the context to the template, and sending that to the browser.